# Access selecting data based on earliest or latest time

Tags: ms-access

I am parsing an access log I want to create another table (table B) from the first table (Raw table A) with the following criteria.

```
Raw Table A Data
full_name, reg_id, date, time
Matt, 1, 05/01/2013, 08:00:00
Jenny, 2, 05/01/2013, 08:00:01
Ueno, 3, 05/01/2013, 08:00:02
Matt, 1, 05/01/2013, 16:30:00
Jenny, 2, 05/01/2013, 17:00:00
Ueno, 3, 05/01/2013, 17:15:00
Matt, 1, 05/02/2013, 07:34:00
Ueno, 3, 05/02/2013, 08:01:00
Matt, 1, 05/02/2013, 12:00:00
Ueno, 3, 05/02/2013, 14:00:00
Jenny, 2, 05/02/2013, 17:00:00
```

I would like to extract the first timestamp for each reg_id for each day and insert them into a new table (Table B).

Should I do this via VBA or via a SELECT statement/query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, this is all you need:

```
SELECT TableA.reg_id, TableA.[date], Min(TableA.[time]) AS [time] INTO TableB
FROM TableA
GROUP BY TableA.reg_id, TableA.[date];
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stumped on the following: "TableA.[date]" and "Min(TableA.[time]) As [time]" What do the [] mean?